Removing user removes user meta?
Sorry for the basic question, but I couldn't find an answer by reading the docs. When we delete user in the WP admin area, will WP delete the associated user_meta too?

look here : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.6.2/src/wp-admin/includes/user.php#L438

Thank you very much!

@mmm Please, add it as an answer!
